# Insert php sql row record into hidden form input value field

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert sql ID record inside php echo form input value. Values that are inserted manualy via input field (by typing) are being displayed fine. Value inside input (named: potnik) is not being displayed. Is it ignored because is inside echo or is inserted wrong?

```
$sql3 = "
SELECT id, potnik_id, ura, naslov
FROM prevoznik 
ORDER BY HOUR(ura), MINUTE(ura) ASC;
";
$result = $conn->query($sql3);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Spremenjena oblika datuma
        $date = date_create($row["ura"]);
        $ura_pobiranja = date_format($date,"H:i");
        echo "<div class=\"row list  divider-gray\">
                <div class=\"col-1 fs-09 fw-600\">" . $row["id"] . " </div>
                  <div class=\"col-3 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">" . $row["naslov"] . " </div>
                <div class=\"col-1 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">$ura_pobiranja</div>
            ";

        if ($row["naslov"] !== null) {
            echo " <div class=\"col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1\">Nastavi uro<form action='update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\"' method='POST'><input name=\"potnik\"  value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> <input class=\"form-control fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/><input type='submit' value='Posodobi'>  </form></div>";
            echo " </div>";
        }
        else {
            echo " </div>";
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "<div class=\"col flex-vcenter-items fw-100 fs-1\"><i class=\"far fa-frown-open pr-3\"></i>Nimaš še nobenih opravil
                                    </div>";
}
```

> Code that isn't working (**hidden input field value**):

```
echo " <form action='update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\"' method='POST'><input name=\"potnik\"  value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> <input class=\"form-control fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/><input type='submit' value='Posodobi'>  </form></div>";
```

Comment: You have an extra `\"`  after the form action

Comment: It was a typo, I removed \" and value in the hidden field is still not passing $row["id"]

Comment: How do you know that the value is not  displayed correctly? Are ou inspecting the element via devtools or what?

Comment: I inserted custom condition inside update.php to throw me error, That error throws me nothing for that hidden input field and throws me value for manualy entered value at posodobljeni_cas.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Also value "5" is visible if inspecting the element via devtools.

Comment: @I should probably echo value to that hidden input, but since this whole form is already inside echo, double echo is not possible to enter value like:`value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
`

Answer (score 1):

I had post parameters instead of get parameters set for update.php form action

**update.php?id=**

```
echo"Error on update ID:{$_GET['id']} POSODOBLJENI CAS:{$_POST['posodobljeni_cas']}";
```